# Pintar tabla html con array multidimensional

Tags: php, array, bucle-for, foreach, html-tabla

Saludo cordial compañeros.

Tengo un problema con el siguiente ejercicio. Me dan la información de un objeto que viene desde base de datos. El primer dato que aparece es el año "2017". El segundo dato es el mes "12". El tercer dato son los días "1, 4, 5, 6, 12, 13, 14, 26, 27". Existen varias etiquetas de las etapas del proceso "Saldo inicial, Entradas, Salidas, Saldo final".

Esta seria la tabla que necesito hacer en html, donde se deben tener en cuenta los días en cada una etapa de las etapas del proceso y si no hay información del día debo poner un valor 0. Como podemos ver mejor en la imagen adjunta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que llevo pero me arroja otro resultado diferente.

`<?php
$data =
  [
    [
      "2017" => [
        "12" => [
          "1" => ["valor" => 4524],
          "4" => ["valor" => 4530],
          "5" => ["valor" => 4535],
          "6" => ["valor" => 4538],
          "12" => ["valor" => 4538],
          "13" => ["valor" => 4535],
          "14" => ["valor" => 4533],
          "26" => ["valor" => 4531],
          "27" => ["valor" => 4531]
        ]
      ],
      "label" => "Saldo Inicial"
    ],
    [
      "2017" => [
        "12" => [
          "1" => ["valor" => 7, "detalle" => [5179, 5182, 5183, 5180, 5181, 5184, 5178]],
          "4" => ["valor" => 6, "detalle" => [5199, 5189, 5185, 5187, 5190, 5188]],
          "5" => ["valor" => 3, "detalle" => [5229, 5209, 5230]],
          "27" => ["valor" => 60, "detalle" => [5421, 5380, 5418, 5403, 5440, 5383, 5430, 5393, 5402, 5396, 5434, 5439, 5436, 5435, 5387, 5409, 5405, 5438, 5437, 5395, 5390, 5412, 5423, 5407, 5406, 5391, 5431, 5425, 5424, 5429, 5413, 5432, 5392, 5427, 5386, 5415, 5416, 5414, 5419, 5411, 5382, 5384, 5381, 5399, 5408, 5388, 5422, 5428, 5420, 5394, 5441, 5400, 5397, 5401, 5433, 5410, 5417, 5398, 5426, 5389]]]
      ],
      "label" => "Entradas",
      "total" => 76
    ],
    [
      "2017" => [
        "12" => [
          "1" => ["valor" => 1, "detalle" => [5178]],
          "4" => ["valor" => 1, "detalle" => [5190]],
          "12" => ["valor" => 3, "detalle" => [5179, 5180, 5180]],
          "13" => ["valor" => 2, "detalle" => [5183, 5185]],
          "14" => ["valor" => 2, "detalle" => [5167, 5184]]]
      ],
      "label" => "Salidas",
      "total" => 9
    ],
    [
      "2017" => [
        "12" => [
          "1" => ["valor" => 4530],
          "4" => ["valor" => 4535],
          "5" => ["valor" => 4538],
          "6" => ["valor" => 4538],
          "12" => ["valor" => 4535],
          "13" => ["valor" => 4533],
          "14" => ["valor" => 4531],
          "26" => ["valor" => 4531],
          "27" => ["valor" => 4591]
        ]
      ],
      "label" => "Saldo Final"
    ]
  ];
?>


<?php

foreach ($data as $categoria) {
  if ($categoria['label'] == 'Saldo Inicial') {
    foreach ($categoria as $año => $dataA) {
      if ($año != 'label' && $año != 'total') {
        foreach ($dataA as $mes => $dataM) {
          $size = count($dataM);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


$table = "<table class='reporte-ware' border='1' width='100%'><thead class='headerT'><tr>";

foreach ($data as $categoria) {
  if ($categoria['label'] == 'Saldo Inicial') {
    foreach ($categoria as $año => $dataA) {
      if ($año != 'label' && $año != 'total') {
        $table .= "<tr align='center'><th>AÑO</th><th colspan='" . $size . "'>$año</th></tr>";
        foreach ($dataA as $mes => $dataM) {
          $table .= "<tr align='center'><th>MES</th><th colspan='" . $size . "'>$mes</th></tr>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

$table .= "<tr align='center'><th>DIAS</th>";

foreach ($data as $movimiento) {
  if ($movimiento['label'] == 'Saldo Inicial') {
    foreach ($movimiento as $año => $dataAño) {
      if ($año != 'label' && $año != 'total') {
        foreach ($dataAño as $mes => $dataMes) {
          $diasTotales = array_keys($dataMes);
          foreach ($dataMes as $dia => $datosDia) {
            $table .= "<th>$dia</th>";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    $table .= "</tr></thead>";
  }
  $table .= "<tbody><tr>";
  $table .= "<td>{$movimiento['label']}</td>";

  foreach ($movimiento as $año => $datosAño) {
    if ($año != 'label' && $año != 'total') {
      foreach ($datosAño as $mes => $datosMes) {
        foreach ($datosMes as $dia => $datosDia) {
          //echo "<h5>$dia</h5>";
          $table .= "<td align='center'>{$datosAño[$mes][$dia]['valor']}</td>";
          //$table .= "<td>0</td>";
          //$table .= "<td>{$datosAño[$mes][$dia]['valor']}</td>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

$table .= "</tr>";
$table .= "</tbody>";
$table .= "</table>";

echo $table;

?>`

[image: Esta es la tabla que me sale a mi]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu problema es sobre php y css no? que tiene que ver la etiqueta array? por favor, usa las etiquetas correctas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reorganiza los datos para leerlos mas fácil, haciendo la etiqueta una clave.
2. En lugar de recorrer los valores, recorre las etiquetas y luego días.
3. Evalúa si existe el valor para renglón-columna, en caso contrario muestra cero.

```
$categorias = []; // Datos re-organizados
foreach ($data as $categoria)
    foreach( $categoria as $clave => $valor )
        if( is_integer($clave) && is_array($valor) ){
            $año = $clave;
            $mes = array_keys($valor)[0];
            $categorias[$categoria['label']][$clave] = $valor;
        }
$dias = array_keys($categorias['Saldo Inicial'][$año][$mes]); // Columnas

$table = "<table class='reporte-ware' border='1' width='100%'>"
       . "<tr align='center'><th>AÑO</th><th colspan='" . count($dias) . "'>$año</th></tr>"
       . "<tr align='center'><th>MES</th><th colspan='" . count($dias) . "'>$mes</th></tr>"
       ;

$table .= "<tr align='center'><th>DIAS</th>";
foreach( $dias as $dia )
    $table .= "<th>$dia</th>";

$table .= '<tbody>';
foreach( $categorias as $label => $datosAño ){
    $table .= "<tr><td>$label</td>";
    foreach ( $dias as $dia ) {
        $valor = ( isset( $datosAño[$año][$mes][$dia]['valor']) 
                 ? $datosAño[$año][$mes][$dia]['valor']
                 : 0
                 );
        $table .= "<td align='center'>$valor</td>";
    }
    $table .= "</tr>";
}
$table .= "</tbody>";

$table .= "</table>";

echo $table;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @Sal. Me funciono muy bien